# Filter Everything Pro Not Getting Original Category (Cat ID 1)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I have a unique problem. The Plugin "Filter Everything Pro" is not getting the data from the original WordPress category (Cat ID 1), which is "General", I believe, when you first install WordPress.

Well, that's our main category on the website (Namely, Publications). So, that is important. Did anyone have this problem before? When I'm using the Plugin to filter my blog posts, on the category filter section, the original category (Cat ID 1) is not showing, which is interesting.

Not only that, but any subcategory under that main category (Cat ID 1) is also not showing in the filter section.

But other categories (Cat ID 2, subcategories of Cat ID 2 and beyond) are showing fine.

Kind regards.

Comment: You should probably contact their support about this, https://filtereverything.pro/support/

Comment: Thank you for your response @CBroe ; I have also tried reaching out via the support forum, support comment section, and e-mail. I just wanted to write here in case someone knows a solution / had the same problem.